# Postgresql date range

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a calendar with events:
Calendar always have a start point and end point ( example 29.04.2014 till 09.6.2014)

Events are shown from this date range:

```
AND DATE(event_from) >= DATE(?) //29.04.2014
AND DATE(event_to) <= DATE(?) //09.6.2014
```

But if event starts 28.04 and ends 10.6.2014 it want shown in calendar

How can I show this event if it exceeds the range, but also remains in range

Thanks to klin:

All together

`AND (daterange(DATE(event_from), DATE(event_to)) && daterange(DATE(?), DATE(?))
   OR(
       DATE(event_from) >= DATE(?) AND DATE(event_to) <= DATE(?)
   )
)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the type [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rangetypes.html) and [overlap operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-range.html):

```
with ranges(event_from, event_to) as (
values 
    ('2016-04-01'::date, '2016-06-01'::date),
    ('2016-01-01', '2016-03-01'),
    ('2016-05-01', '2016-05-15')
)

select *
from ranges
where daterange(event_from, event_to) && daterange('2016-05-01', '2016-05-31');

 event_from |  event_to  
------------+------------
 2016-04-01 | 2016-06-01
 2016-05-01 | 2016-05-15
(2 rows)
```

Comment: thank you for solution, but can't change datatype of column

Comment: You don't have to. Use `daterange` only in `where` clause, just like in the example.

Comment: using `daterange(DATE(event_from), DATE(event_to)) && daterange(DATE('2016-05-01'), DATE('2016-05-31'))` Solved it but not getting records that is only one day event.

Comment: For one day event use one day daterange, e.g. `daterange('2016-01-01', '2016-01-01')`, this works well.